# VLC: Crop/hide part of screen?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I want to crop/hide/cover up the bottom right hand bits (where this "Bally Sports" network shows me scores of games I haven't watched and lots of other unending annoying information):

[image]

Like this:

[image]

One crude workaround I can think of to have another window placed at the bottom right corner. But this doesn't work if I have VLC in always-on-top mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want to crop/hide/cover up the bottom right hand bits

You need to overlay the part of the video you want to hide with a mask you create of the correct size.

> - Open your video and pause it.
> - Click on Tools > Effects and Filters. [CTRL + E or Command + E]
> - Switch to the Video Effects > Overlay
> - Click on the three dots … to browse the appropriately sized Mask.
> - (You will notice a blur on the top left corner)
> - Move it and place it over the logo by inputting values in the Top and Left
> - Hit Close when you are done.
>
> The mask that you place is for covering up something that you want to
> obstruct from view. Its position should be stationary because the mask
> won't move automatically. Also note that, it doesn’t make a permanent
> change to the video.

Source: [How to Hide or Blur Logos of Videos Playing in VLC](https://vlchelp.com/hide-blur-logos-videos/)